# how to setstate in if react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, if-statement

Hello I'm trying to export `exportTest` to another js file and do re-render. I'm trying it like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

var n;
export var exportTest;

function foo()
{
  //doing something and giving back n as 1 or 0
}

export default function App () {

  const [test,setTest] = useState();
  if(n == 0)
  {
    //doing something
    setTest('n is zero')
  }
  else
  {
    //doing something
    setTest('n is not zero')
  }
  exportTest=test

  return(
     <View>
       ...
       ...
       ...
     </View>
  );
}
```

I'm getting error `too meny re-renders`, because I'm doing `setTest` in `if`
How can I do `setTest` once in last line of `if`? `n` is changing in some function, I'm getting it as 1 or 0.
And this is how I'm importing `exportTest` in another file `import {exportTest} from './App.js';`

Comment: Well, `n` is always 0 so yeah it'll rerender over and over again. There's no base case to the recursion, `n` is always 0 or something else, so a `setState` will be called. Every time you call `setState`, it triggers a new render, so you'll want to get to some point where no `setState` is called. All that said, I'm not really sure what this component is supposed to do.

Comment: I want to call ```setTest``` once at end of ```if```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an infinite loop. State and prop changes trigger re-render, and in your case - the re-render triggers a state update. That's why state updates should NEVER be a part of your renderer's logic.

From reactjs.org:

> What does setState do?
>
> setState() schedules an update to a component’s state object. When
> state changes, the component responds by re-rendering

Normally, you would do all your state manipulations on `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps`, and hook's alternative to those is an `Effect Hook`.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // componentWillMount

    return () => {
      // componentWillUnmount
    };
  });
```

Trigger on props updates:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // prop abc changed
  }, [props.abc]);
```

Notice, in the latter example I left out the return statement.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export const exportTest = () => {
  
  const [test,setTest] = useState();

  let n = 0;

  if(n == 0)
  {
    setTest('n is zero')
  }
  else
  {
    setTest('n is not zero')
  }
  exportTest=test

  return(
     ...
     ...
     ...
  );
}
```

Try that. You are importing it as a const hence the {exportTest} import you wrote. You need to export exportTest as a const.

There are a lot of things wrong and you deleted the return so your purpose isn't clear. See if that helps. Feel free to comment again. I recommend cleaning up your code.

Comment: It doesn't work and return isn't that important here, it's just some Views, TouchableOpacity and Text